# MySQL Update query with LIKE in WHERE clause not affecting matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-like

This is driving me crazy. I do a `SELECT` first to make sure records exist:

```
Select * from gems WHERE page2 like '%acids-bases-salts%'
```

and get

```
Showing rows 0 - 8 ( 9 total, Query took 0.0012 sec)
```

Then try to `UPDATE` to change those records:

```
UPDATE gems SET page2 = replace(page2, 'acids-bases-salts', 'abs') WHERE page2 LIKE '%acids-bases-salts%'
```

and get

```
0 rows affected. ( Query took 0.0019 sec )
```

What am I missing? This is  simple one time query so I am not worried about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it. The `replace()` is case sensitive but the WHERE clause is not.