# MySQL LIKE matching at the end of the string

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm trying to figure out why these two like statements are evaluated equally.  In the first, I'm doing a simple select which returns 22 rows.  In the second, I'm expecting that my update / replace should also return 22 rows affected. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?  These should match strings like "I got a knee mri".

```
SET @acro = 'mri';

SELECT title FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE concat('% ', @acro);
```

//returns n rows

```
UPDATE mytable
SET title = REPLACE(title, CONCAT(' ', @acro), CONCAT(' ', UPPER(@acro)))
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('% ', @acro);
```

//returns 0 rows

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text,
  `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=119232 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It might be related to the collation of your table. Please post your tables `CREATE`-statement to verify further.

Comment: Its utf8_ci with no collation and default charset utf_8.

Comment: Please add your `CREATE TABLE`-statement to verify further. I've tried your use case with a table like this: `CREATE TABLE mytable (
  mid int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (mid)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`  ... (collation `utf8_general_ci`) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM mytable;` to show the collation.

Comment: The collation is utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 0):

The "rows affected" count is the number of rows that were modified, not the number of rows that were matched.

One explanation is that the column title is using a case insensitive collation, that is, a characterset that has a name ending in `_ci`.

It's possible that 22 rows were "matched", but no rows needed to be modified.

If the column is defined with characterset/collation `latin1_swedish_ci`, you could try comparing the results from a query like this:

```
SET @acro = _latin1'mri';

SELECT title
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE title COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('% ', @acro));
                                   ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, here's the answer:  [MySQL Update query with LIKE in WHERE clause not affecting matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038101/mysql-update-query-with-like-in-where-clause-not-affecting-matching-rows?rq=1)

Replace() is case sensitive but like is not.